# Script Runs Incorrect Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

Take a look at the follow HTML and JS:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="alertFunction()">Choose Option Modal (Button 1)</button>

<button onclick="alertFunction2()">Veloce Modal (Button 2)</button>
```

JS:

```
function alertFunction() {
    alert("Please choose relevant options before adding to cart.");
}

function alertFunction2() {
  alert("item(s) added to your cart");
}


$(function() {

(function() {
    window.alert = function(text) {
        if (text.indexOf("Please choose relevant options before")) {
            console.log('Choose an Option Modal Open (Button 1)');
        } else if (text.indexOf("item(s) added to your cart")) {
            console.log('Veloce Modal Open (Button 2)');
        } 
    };
})();  

});
```

In the above script if I click a button, either 1 or 2, an alert is triggered. Next, the alert text is taken by the JS and we check the text of the alert. If the text contains certain words then a function is ran, in this case just a `console.log`.

The problem I have is when I click Button 1 the `console.log` for button 2 is what shows. The same happens if I click Button 2, the `console.log` for button 1 is shown.

What do I have wrong and how do I fix the problem?

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ab502ech/) with a working example of the issue.

Comment: why are you overwriting `window.alert`?

Comment: `indexOf` does *not* return a boolean.  It returns the *index* in the string, or `-1` if it's not found.

Comment: @k-nut - When a button is clicked in my eCommerce shop my CMS responds with an alert. I am overriding that behavior and showing a modal of my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf()` returns the first index at which the substring is found. In your case, when the text matches, `0` is returned, which is evaluated as `false`. Anything else, including `-1` (meaning not found) evaluates as `true`.

Check the return value:

```
if (text.indexOf("Please choose relevant options before") > -1) {
        console.log('Choose an Option Modal Open (Button 1)');
    } else if (text.indexOf("item(s) added to your cart") > -1) {
        console.log('Veloce Modal Open (Button 2)');
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fd7yn78u/